# Why doesn't R throw an error when an argument used to subscript a list is missing?

Tags: r

I recently had some bizarre errors that I tracked down to some code far earlier that I thought would have thrown an error but did not.

Take the following function as an example:

```
foo <- function(x) {
    list(3)[[x]]
}
```

Why does calling `foo()` not throw an error? `foo()` apparently lets the expression evaluate to NULL. I know that R does lazy evaluation and doesn't complain about x being missing unless it needs the value of x, but doesn't it need x to evaluate this expression?

If the function was instead:

```
foo <- function(x) {
    list(x)
}
```

There would be no getting around evaluating x, and `foo()` throws the error "Error in foo() : argument 'x' is missing, with no default".

If you understand what might be going on here, I'd love to learn what it is so I can better notice when my code might cause this sort of behavior. Not that I'm planning to call functions as carelessly as this!

I've looked at a couple of other SO questions about missing arguments, but couldn't tell if any of them matched this particular situation.

Thank you, R Community!

Answer (score 3):

The difference is that the `[[` operation tolerates missing values but `list()` does not. When parameters are not passed, they are "missing" for example

```
foo <- function(x) {
  print(missing(x))
}
foo()
# [1] TRUE
foo(1)
# [1] FALSE
```

Also note you get an error if you use a different variable name

```
foo <- function(x) {
    list(3)[[bar]]
}
# Error in foo() : object 'bar' not found
```

So it is finding the `x` value, but it's evaluating to `missing`. Because the `[` and `[[` operators support skipping over indexes in a special way, missing is actually a valid parameter option. Consider the closely related `[` operation

```
foo <- function(r, c) {
  matrix(1:15, ncol=3)[r, c]  
} 
foo()
#      [,1] [,2] [,3]
# [1,]    1    6   11
# [2,]    2    7   12
# [3,]    3    8   13
# [4,]    4    9   14
# [5,]    5   10   15
foo(r=1)
# [1]  1  6 11
foo(c=2)
# [1]  6  7  8  9 10
```

Note how in these examples a missing value basically indicates all values for unspecified dimension.

So the issue is calling `list()` is subtly different from calling `list(<magic missing value>)` because it's kind of hard to create missing value. But basically `list()` does not expect such a value to be explicitly passed as parameter. For example `list(1,,2)` also throws an error because you basically have a missing value in the second parameter and `list()` doesn't like that.

Another way to see this is to use `substitute()` to build the expression and then view it as list. For example

```
foo <- function(x) {
  substitute(list(x))
}
as.list(foo())
# [[1]]
# list 
# [[2]]
# 

foo <- function(x) {
  substitute(list())
}
as.list(foo())
# [[1]]
# list
```

You'll see the first version has that extra "missing" part that's being passed to the function.

As pointed out in @MikaelJagan's response, it was a bit ambiguous exactly what `[[]]` with a missing value should return. In newer versions of R, this syntax is no longer allowed. But in version <4.3, it would return the first unnamed element in the list.

Answer (score 3):

Your `foo()` call throws a "missing subscript" error in R version 4.3.0 and newer.  See the discussions in [Bug 18004](https://bugs.r-project.org/show_bug.cgi?id=18004) and [Bug 18367](https://bugs.r-project.org/show_bug.cgi?id=18367).

```
> getRversion()
[1] '4.3.2'
> foo <- function(x) list(3)[[x]]
> foo()
Error in list(3)[[x]] : missing subscript
```

There is a corresponding NEWS entry rendered by the following call to `news`:

```r
news(Version == "4.3.0" & Category == "BUG FIXES" & grepl("[[]]", Text, fixed = TRUE))
```

Comment: Thank you for your response! My R version is indeed earlier than 4.3.0 (4.2.1) so this makes a lot of sense. I'm happy to learn of R news as well and will monitor it in the future to find out about these sorts of changes.